# Scale WPF Shape

Tags: wpf, scale, shapes

I have geometry points that are based on EASTING and NORTHING with a min/max of (794975, 823750) and (7484425,7516450).

I want to draw various points in-between these values on a WPF Window.

How do I draw a geometry point within those ranges without it going outside the screen size?

I am using the following XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DrillholePoints}"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding ellipse}"
                  Stroke="Blue"
                  StrokeThickness="2" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Your question content doesn't seem to match the title. To scale, I would put everything in a viewbox. This is how the map in our game works. To ensure everything fits I would work out what the boundaries of the map translate into in terms of points.  So the left boundary is x = zero in terms of the canvas but easting n. The right boundary is easting z etc. Then ensure you don't go over them.

Comment: In order to scale a Shape without also scaling its StrokeThickness, use the Transform property of the Geometry that is assigned to its Data property, i.e. your `ellipse` view model property here.

Comment: You need to bind the itemcontainer canvas.left and canvas.top to position each spot. If you want a spot centred on a known point then the way a path will work by default is to draw the top left bound at that point. An ellipsegeometry, however, will have that point as it's centre.

Comment: The shape is presumably just going to be an ellipse or spot. I don't follow why you'd particularly want to scale it. If the map is supposed to scale you could make that the background of the canvas and stretch it uniform. Calculate the locations based on the effective scaling. The ellipses will be separate objects and always the same size.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear on my question and I am using incorrect terminology.
I have multiple points and I want to display them in WPF.
The points fit within the range specified.
Much like a MAP but I don't want to use maps as the info will be used offline and MAPS are slow.
I want to be able to zoom in out as per MAPS but without the MAPS overhead.